# Caffe SoftmaxWithLoss Error

Tags: c++, neural-network, caffe

I get this error message when I try to solve my neural network:

```
    Check failed: label_value < prob_.shape(softmax_axis_) (1 vs. 1)
```

My labels are all either 0 or 1. When I tried out this [example](https://github.com/shi-yan/caffe/tree/master/examples/cpp_xor) it worked with 0 and 1 labels. So my assumption is that the error is in the second part:

```
    prob_.shape(softmax_axis_)
```

I looked it up in the source code and I don't understand how my source code or prototxt files influence this value.

Can someone explain what is going on and how I can get my softmax layer to accept labels with a value of 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `"SoftmaxWithLoss"` layer to predict binary labels, your "class-probability" vector should by of length 2 (and not 1).
You are getting an error saying your "class-probability" vector (aka "`prob_`") is of dimension 1 while it should be at least 2 (that is **strictly** larger than largest label).

Check `num_output` parameter in the layer producing the class probabilities.

Alternatively, for binary classification, consider using [`"SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/sigmoidcrossentropyloss.html)